# How to filter/get with 2 word __str__

Tags: django

Model has:

`def __str__(self):
    return '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)`

I want to do a `objects.get` where the first name and last name are the same to allow users to have the same first name but still specifiy.

Tried having the `__str__` as the `id` but can't be an int apparently.

Also tried splitting the name with `.split()` but it gave the error `object has no attribute 'split'`.

How I tried the split:

```
full_name = interaction_info.candidate_id
split_name = split()
candidate_first = split_name[0]
candidate_last = split_name[1]
candidate_link = Candidate.objects.filter(first_name__exact=candidate_first).filter(last_name__exact=candidate_last)
```

I want to be able to find the entry where the first name and last name match the return self string. But cannot get it to work.

EDIT:
I have a page of 'interactions' these are related to a 'candidate', `candidate_id` is a foreign key on the `Interaction` model. The page of interactions shows a table with all interactions in, when a row is clicked, it should redirect to a page showing only details of that interaction. So from the foreign key I need to access the primary key of the candidate table, this is what I am struggling with.

Comment: objects.get performs a database lookup. __str__() determines what is shown if you do ```print(Model) or str(Model)```.

Comment: using your example, try: ```candidate_link = Candidate.objects.filter(first_name__exact=candidate_first, last_name__exact=candidate_last)```

Comment: This looks like exactly what you want: https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-orm-cookbook/en/latest/f_query.html

Comment: Made an edit to explain better, any more advice?

Comment: ```Candidate.objects.get(first_name=F("last_name"))```

Comment: what does the F mean?